# Get the diff in Git for files that have been renamed and then significantly changed. This does not currently work properly for me

Tags: git, version-control, diff

I have a commit in git that moves a lot of files (Git recognizes these are moves/renames), then another commit after significantly modified some of these files.

Everything shows up as expected on an individual commit basis, but when i diff an old commit to the latest commit on branch, git shows some of these files as deleted then added.

If i do the following command, git correctly sees the renames and modifies:

```
git log --follow --name-status -M  branch  -- */fileName
```

if i do the following:

```
git diff --follow -M  branch -- */fileName
```

Git shows me that the entire file was deleted then re-added (red and green text).

I think what is happening is that when doing a diff, git doesn't go through all commits in between but instead compares the first commit contents directly to the last and since the file changed significantly in one commit it's not considered a modification to the original.

Is there a way to get a proper diff of only what has changed without explicitly listing the old and new path of the file to git?

Comment: Have you tried `git log -p`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For a second I thought it gave me what I wanted, but it just shows the diff per commit.  What I want is the combined diff across renames and multiple commits.  For example the diff between HEAD and HEAD~20 of a particular file that was renamed in one of the 20 commits then modified extensively in others.

Answer (score 0):

Since `git` doesn't actually track file moves/renames, but detects them on demand, `git` doesn't really "know" that, e.g. file `a` became `some/subdir/z`. The `-M` option (and a few others) to `diff` and some other commands allow specifying a threshold for determining file similarity, so that, e.g. `git diff -M25% a some/subdir/z` will consider `some/subdir/z` to be the result of moving `a` and then modifying it if there is at least a 25% similarity between the two. Of course, setting a low threshold might falsely "identify" a bunch of other rename-edit pairs, too, so use with caution...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I already know this, my issue is that git diff is essentially useless unless it looks through the history as git log does.  Ie. git log detects the rename, all I need git diff to do is parse the history to find out which files were renamed and then show the diff.  It seems like it's a serious weakness in git to not follow the changelog when doing diffs.  I understand this could be a choice to improve performance, but then they should have a flag for it same as git log --follow.